# How to run BDD Cucumber Mobile Test in parallel Thread

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I have a BDD Cucumber framework and 6 tests are in feature file. I want to execute 6 tests in 2 devices so that 3 test cases will be executed in each devices to reduce the overall run time by 50%

However the current framework runs all 6 test cases in each devices i.e. runs 12 tests.

Here is my testng.. Can you please help

````
<!DOCTYPE suite PUBLIC "SYSTEM" "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="2" verbose="1" parallel="tests">
    <test name="emulator5554">
        <parameter name="udid" value="emulator-5554"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.runners.DeviceTestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="emulator5558">
        <parameter name="udid" value="emulator-5558"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.runners.DeviceTestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>```
````

Comment: Can someone please help?